# Is there a way to handle quoted null String in Scala?

Tags: scala

I would like to have the String, `"null"` converted to an `Option[String] = None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val x = "null" 
Option(x).filter(_!="null")
```

Comment: `filterNot(_ == "null")` =)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
    def convertToOption(value: String): Option[String] = {
          value match {
            case "null" => None
            case  _ => Some(value)
      }
   }
```